# Python - How to check Booleans inside a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm without clues on how to do this. I've a list:

```
list_something = [5, 6, 8]
```

And I've a method is_valid()

```
def is_valid(number):
    return type(number) is int
```

How can I check at once if the 3 numbers are all Integers inside a for loop?

```
for item in list_something:
```

At the end of the for loop I need to have a variable called "all_list_something" and will have the value of True or False. If all the numbers in the list are Integer, the value is True. If only one fails to be Integer, the value will be false.

Any clues on the best way to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: You've got a variety of answers: I'll just point out that your `is_valid` function is basically (and unless you don't want objects that inherit from int to be allowed) `isinstance(number, int)`

Comment: @JonClements: or `isinstance(number, (int, long))` in Python 2.  [I'll be very happy when everyone switches to Python 3 and we can forget about that annoyance..]

Comment: @DSM *just* that annoyance? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `all` and `map`:

```
all_list_something = all(map(is_valid, list_something))
```

Using `itertools.imap` would allow this to short-circuit (meaning that if the first element is invalid, it never checks the rest):

```
import itertools
all_list_something = all(itertools.imap(is_valid, list_something))
```

Answer (score 10):

A generator comprehension can improve readability over a map for some.

```
all_list_something = all(is_valid(x) for x in list_something)
```

Comment: One other advantage that the gencomp has over the `map` -- in Python 2, anyway -- is that it's lazy and short-circuits as soon as a `False` is found, whereas the `map` approach doesn't.  [That may be worded confusingly: the `all` still short-circuits, it's the `map` which generates the whole list.]

Comment: Notably, unless one uses `itertools.imap` (which I didn't for the sake of conciseness), this is faster than my `map` answer.

Comment: Also, this is more "Pythonic"

Answer (score 4):

Since the question asks about how to do it in a for loop, I thought I'd include such an answer:

```
all_list_something = True
for item in list_something:
    if not is_valid(item):
       all_list_something = False
       break
```

But really, David or cmh's answer is the way to go.

Comment: I was just writing an answer like this up. The other ones are very much correct, but so is this one. This answer demonstrates that the other methods are not magical at all and are shorthand for a solution to a frequent problem.

Comment: One tweak would be to add `break` after `all_list_something = False` so that you stop searching after you know the output is `False`.

Comment: Thanks DSM :) That's why I like contributing here! I didn't even think of that.